# Why is my whatsapp message not being sent?

Tags: whatsapp

Testing with Postman, I'm trying to send a message per [the glitch example project from docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/sample-app-endpoints#whatsapp-business-platform-cloud-api)

I'm trying to write an API endpoint I can hit with a webhook when people send a message to my Org's whatsapp number. The API would send an automated response.

When I send the POST, with the following body to `https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/redacted/messages` it comes back with the following response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#131030) Recipient phone number not in allowed list",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 131030,
    "error_data": {
      "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
      "details": "Recipient phone number not in allowed list: Add recipient phone number to recipient list and try again."
    },
    "error_subcode": 2655007,
    "fbtrace_id": "A5YKQbpB0PEaaA-gIROEv-n"
  }
}
```

The error code isn't list one [the error codes page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/support/error-codes), nor can I find anything about adding a recipient phone number anyway (it doesn't make sense to require a pre-defined list of recipient phone numbers to which I can send messages).

Here's the message body:

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "to": "redacted",
  "text": {
    "body": "Ack: Hello world"
  }
}
```

How do I get the message sent? I'm not able to proceed with development of my app until I can send a message.

Comment: If you are using testing phone number that is provided by whatsapp then you have to add recipient's phone number, you can add up to 5 phone numbers only.

Comment: Where do I do this?

Comment: Where did you find your phone number id and business id details?

Comment: Answering a direct question with another question is not helpful. I already verified my phone number there as a recipient phone number.

Comment: The error message explains everything, which is why I asked common questions if you have done that properly then this won't happen.
You have implemented or used something wrong so without knowing the details I can not answer your question.
Follow the steps clearly explained in [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started), If you are sure about your implementation then you can [direct support](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/contact-support) on FB.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @RahmanHaroon no I went with Twilio integration

Comment: I have the same problem and when I try to add myself as test user it says "you can't add yourself as a test user". Zukerberg s*cks

Answer (score 6):

Just Remove + from your mobile number and add you country code before your number.

Then its working fine.

Request Body:

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "to": "91xxxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "template",
    "template": {
        "name": "hello_world",
        "language": {
            "code": "en_US"
        }
    }
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "input": "91xxxxxxxxxx",
            "wa_id": "91xxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ],
    "messages": [
        {
            "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE3NTM4OTE4MzIyFQIAERgSOERCM0ZDOTJFMDk1RjBFNURBAA=="
        }
    ]
}
```

[for Your Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGlaP.png)

Comment: yes!!! but wait... This got rid of the error, however I never received the text message.  lol

Comment: You were right I just had to respond to the first message from the Meta test number or add it to contacts otherwise the client app just treated it like spam and didn't let the messages deliver

Comment: it works because it is considered as "the user initiated a conversation" , but after 24 hours it will stop working because you need to initiate conversation every day. it is how then rate app usage and charge per volume for the use of the API.  zukerberg s*cks

Answer (score 1):

The error for Postman comes from a mislabelling in the template file for the variable {{Recipient-WA-ID}}. The environment variable should be renamed to this from {{Recipient-Phone-Number}} (or vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error code and message here.

I was debugging it and see that the *from* number is a little different than the number I had registered when I will echo the message back.

You can put the number of phone hard coded that you have registered before to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Add the Recipient number to the allowed number list before you send a message.

You Can find it at the following path:
Your App> WhatsApp> Getting Started> To (Drop down)

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDCk1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar error, Found out that.
I generated token and then assigned assets to it.

It should be the other way round.
First assign assets (your app) and then generate token.